# Homepage accessible to non-members though title of the page says : "Access Denied"

Tags: 7, users

Since i upgraded to 7.8 i noticed that the homepage of my site now displays a title of "Access denied" as it used to be "Welcome to my site". Though it remains perfectly accessible to non-members.

I'don t recall modifying any permission so far so i doubt this is because of my code. Have anyone experienced that ? How could it be fixed ? Do i need to override menu title for that page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what caused that though i solve it by creating a custom menu item with HOOK_menu giving it full permissions, then i added that new menu item in the homepage field in site configuration .

Comment: did you run update.php?

Comment: Yes i did bob, thanks for suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

The site's default front page, under Admin > Configuration > Site Information, was set to content/home-page, once I removed this path and saved configuration, the 'Access Denied' message disappeared from the browser tab.